# create and delete input element with angularjs directives jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was wondering if we could create and delete an input element of type file with `angularjs` directive in it. For example,

```
<input type="file" name="attachment0" id="attachment0" custom-on-change="uploadfile" ng-show="attachFile" multiple/>
```

Here is custom-on-change is a directive i have defined to trigger `uploadfile()` function when an input file is loaded.  I know this can be done using `angularjs` templates, but i want to know if this can be done using `jquery` or `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try this.

```
function addField(){
  $('form input:file').last().after($('<input type="file" name="files[]" class="file" /><br />'));
}
```

Comment: And i want to add the angularjs directives also, if i add using this method, it does'nt  implement angularjs features

Comment: You could have a container div which will harbor the new file input fields and a button to add new inputs:  $('#addFile').click(function() {
    // when the add file button is clicked append
    // a new <input type="file" name="someName" />
    // to a filesContainer div
    $('#filesContainer').append(
        $('<input/>').attr('type', 'file').attr('name', 'someName')
    );
});

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not allowed to post comments I'll write right here :d

with jQuery you can do something like this

```
var input = jQuery("<input>", {
    'type': 'file',
'name': 'attachment0',
'id': 'attachment0',
'multiple': true
//other attributes in here
}).on('click',uploadfile);
```

Now you can add you variable anywhere in page with `jQuery(your_element).append(input)`.
In uploadfile function **this** is your input variable.

Comment: Hello teoflavian, uploadfile is a function defined using the scope variable, i doubt this will call uploadfile() function.

Comment: in this case you can add a callback function:
jQuery(....).on('click',function(event){ $scope.uploadfile() })